# We have eight balls. Find E[X], E[Y]

Tags: probability

We have 8 balls numbered 1,2,...8. We draw randomly one ball. Let $X$ be smallest number in the box after removal, $Y$ the greatest number in the box after removal. Find $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$?

How to find range of $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $X$ can either be $1$ or $2$.
$$X = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{If the ball removed is }1\\ 1 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$
Hence, $\mathbb{P}(X=1) = \dfrac78$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=2) = \dfrac18$. Hence, $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \dfrac78 \times 1 + \dfrac18 \times 2 = \dfrac98$$

Similarly, $Y$ can either be $7$ or $8$.
$$Y = \begin{cases} 7 & \text{If the ball removed is }8\\ 8 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$
Hence, $\mathbb{P}(Y=7) = \dfrac18$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y=8) = \dfrac78$. Hence, $$\mathbb{E}(Y) = \dfrac78 \times 8 + \dfrac18 \times 7 = \dfrac{63}8$$